# Regex matching a whole URL subpart that is not followed with a specific whole subpart

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to not be able to have a match if path string has a specific word

e.g. If quotes is included in the string, there shouldn't be any match.

But, `/love/something/here` and others should be okay.

```
/love/quotes
```

Here's what I have so far: https://rubular.com/r/W7EjN9KWIN5Jpa

I've tried the ff:

```
([^\/love\/quotes]|\/love(.*))
\/love(^(quotes).)*
```

^ But, still keeps getting one or 2 matches

Sorry, I'm new to Regex.

Comment: `\/love(?!\/quotes)\b.*`? But should `/love/quotes123/` or `/love/quotes-123/` pass?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! It worked. Just want to learn and understand. So, that `\b` plays an important role regarding word boundary? And, does `?!` means negating?

Comment: It works to some extent. What boundary do you need here? `/` or end of string? I think word boundary is a bit too generic here and will allow more matches if you need to match `love` and fail the subsequent `quotes` as full path subparts. Try `\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/]))(?![^\/]).*` (in Rubular, `\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/\n]))(?![^\/\n]).*`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah just the matched `love`. My code would need to `gsub` or substitute matched `love` with another string. But, if there's a `quotes` word in there, the substitution must not be addressed. Thanks again.

Comment: So, which is the solution? #1 or #2?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the solution would be this one `\/love(?!\/quotes\b)` cause this one captures just `love` keyword.

Comment: But it will also match `/love` in `/love-something`. Maybe `\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/]))(?![^\/])` will be better? (when testing online, use `\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/\n]))(?![^\/\n])`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah haven't tried thoroughly. But, I'll have a look @ Rubular. Thanks.

Comment: See https://rubular.com/r/LT8QopC7ObmQmt. With the negated character classes, people often test the patterns wrong in online testers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - that's amazing! Thanks a lot! I have to learn more Regex stuff

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - sorry, is there any way to have anything after `love` to be the matched group, except if it's `quotes`? https://rubular.com/r/CAjdgXtrncnucF

Comment: Append it to the regex, https://rubular.com/r/V4HCL63fXfGFJg. Actually, it can be even simplified in this case, see the solution added to my answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - ah ok got it. thanks! so that's how matched groups work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match a whole URL subpart that is not followed with a specific whole subpart.

You need a negative lookahead and, in this case, your boundaries are `(?![^\/])`, equal to `(?=\/|\z)`, that is, `/` or end of string.

To just match `/love` use

```
\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/]))(?![^\/])
```

See [this regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/TQpqJSpvVdNIiv)

To also capture all after `/love`, use

```
\/love(?!\/quotes(?![^\/]))(\/.*)?\z
```

See the [regex demo](https://rubular.com/r/3fJNtoiriHtB10)

**Details**

- `\/love` - `/love` substring
- `(?!\/quotes(?![^\/]))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current position, there is `/quotes` followed with `/` or end of string position
- `(?![^\/])` - `/` or end of string required immediately after `/love`
- `(.*)` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `(\/.*)?` - an optional capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of `/` and then any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars, as many as possible
- `\z` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks again for the help! Amazing Regex skills!

Answer (score 1):

**Regular expression**

```
bad_word = "quotes"
```

The following regular expression matches the string only if the sentence does not contain the word held by `bad_word`.

```
r = /
    \A                     # match the beginning of the string
    (?!                    # begin negative lookahead
      .*#{bad_word}\z      # do not permit string to end with the bad word 
    )                      # end negative lookahead 
    (?=                    # begin a positive lookahead
      (?:                  # begin a non-capture group
        (?!                # begin a negative lookahead
          \b#{bad_word}\b  # do not match the bad word between word breaks
        )                  # end negative lookahead
        .                  # match a character
      )*                   # end non-capture group and execute >= 0 times
      \z                   # match end-of-string
    )                      # end positive lookahead
    /ix                    # case indifferent and free-spacing modes
```

`r` is conventionally written:

```
r = /\A(?!.*#{bad_word}\z)(?=(?:(?!\b#{bad_word}\b).)*\z)/i
  #=> /\A(?!.*quotes\z)(?=(?:(?!\bquotes\b).)*\z)/i
```

This expression ensures that the string does not contain the bad word. It simply requires that that the string not end with the bad word and that every character in the string is not preceded by the bad word, in which case the bad word cannot be present anywhere in the string. It can be pictured as follows (credit [REGEXPER](https://regexper.com)).

[image]

**Combine `r` with another regular expression**

For any string `str` and regular expression `t` we will attempt to match `str` against the regular expression `/#{r}#{t}/`. If the match against `r` is successful (i.e., `str` does not contain `bad_word`), an attempt is made to match `t`, with the internal regex pointer starting at the beginning of the string. The match obviously fails if `r` is not matched.

**Examples**

```
str = "The Donald believes Colorado borders Mexico."
str[/#{r}.*/] #=> "The Donald believes Colorado borders Mexico." 

str = "The Donald believes Colorado borders Mexico."
str[/#{r}.*\K(?<=borders )\w+/] #=> "Mexico"

str = "The Donald misquotes everybody."
str[/#{r}.*\AThe \KDonald/] #=> "Donald"

str = "Quotes are a politician's friend"
str[/#{r}.*/] #=> nil 

str = "In a sentence quotes are used to repeat something said by someone else."
str[/#{r}In/] #=> nil 

str = "no quotes"
str[/#{r}.*/] #=> nil
```

Note that, for example,

```
/#{r}.*/
  #=> /(?i-mx:\A(?!.*quotes\z)(?=(?:(?!\bquotes\b).)*\z)).*/
```

**Simpler approach**

For a string `str` and regular expression `t` it would course be much easier to compute

```
(str !~ /\bquotes\b/i) && str[t]
```